# how to copy a file from local filesystem to hdfs file system using BDM(Informatica)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, informatica

I am using Informatica version 10.2.1 and using the BDM I want to copy and paste a file from the local file system to the HDFS file system. I am very new to BDM and do not know how to do this.

Currently I have created an object and filled the Read and Write parameters. I am using both `Input Type` and `Output Type` as `command` and issuing the command `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f /tmp/x.csv /tmp/x`

Any help is much appreciated.

### Edit

Pasting an image of the error.

[image]

Comment: `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal` is correct... What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @cricket_007, please see the error attached.

Comment: I do not know this tool, but `command` is not a valid output "file type" according to that error. I think you want `OutputType=csv`

Comment: This is Informatica Developer

Comment: Sure, but `command` is not a "input/output type" it sounds like

Comment: Your question might be better asked at https://network.informatica.com/welcome Otherwise, I would refer to some documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Command` input type in Informatica is used to **read data**. Like `cat filename.txt` stream data out to be read by Informatica and processed further.
It's not meant to **execute** a shell command task. To get this done, you should use `Command task` in the workflow.

ETL tool reads data from one source, performs transformation, and writes to a different place, called target.

What you're trying to do here is a completely different thing, having nothing to do with ETL. Perhaps you can use a simple shell script?

If you'd still like to get this done using Informatica in a proper way, you'd need to define a source, define your target, and map the data ports. Come back if you'd have issues.

One final remark: you'd need to make sure the Integration server can access the source location. It seems to be your local file, it may not be possible to access from remote server.

Comment: You are right @Maciejg. I had a workaround for this issue which is indeed not a neat solution but can of course work. I will write that down as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In BDM 10.2.1 you can have typical source to target flow. For your scenario you can define flat file as source and HDFS as target. BDM is an enterprise etl tool and can be used with hadoop framework.You need to setup hdfs connection for target also in addition to point source to flat file connection.
Image for connection

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMCHx.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G0Jr.png

Image for mapping: